# tkinter listbox insert error "invalid command name ".50054760.50055432"

Tags: python-3.x, listbox, tkinter

I have a database of objects and you can view the items in the database in a listbox and there's a button to remove an item and to create an item. Creating an item opens a dialog window for the item class and then the item's data is stored in the database. I have reproduced the problem with a very simple duplicate of my set-up (see code below).

Every time I add a new item, the addition is successful (it's there the next time I open up the database dialog), but the listbox doesn't insert the item, and when I close the database dialog I get the following error:

> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1442, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)   File "", line 21, in addRecord   File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 2604, in insert
>       self.tk.call((self._w, 'insert', index) + elements)
>   _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".50054760.50055432"

The same problem doesn't come up if I just try to create the object and populate its values without invoking its inputs GUI (which is necessary for the process of inserting things into my database). I've seen a similar error in another thread (sorry, but I can't seem to find it again), where the problem was with multithreading. I'm not aware of any threading that I'm doing and don't want to download yet another package to handle tkinter threading. Any ideas? Workarounds? I'm using Python v3.3 and 64-bit Windows 7, if that helps.

Here's my simplified database code:

```
import tkinter
import traceback

# Test =========================================================================
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        """A database of objects' IDs and values."""

        self.data = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def addRecord(self):
        """Opens up a new item for editing and saves that ability to the
        database."""
        print('hi0')
        newItem = OtherObject()
        newItem.create(self.root)

        print('hi1')
        self.data[newItem.ID] = newItem.value
        print('hi2')
        self.listbox.insert(tkinter.END, self.formatItem(newItem.ID))
        print('hi3')

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def delRecord(self):
        """Removes selected item from the database."""

        try:
            index = self.listbox.curselection()[0]
            selection = self.listbox.get(index)
        except:
            return
        ID = int(selection.split(':')[0])

        self.data.pop(ID)
        self.listbox.delete(index)

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def dataframe(self, master):
        """Assembles a tkinter frame with a scrollbar to view database objects.
        (Returns Frame, Scrollbar widget, Listbox widget)

        master: (Tk or Toplevel) tkinter master widget."""

        frame = tkinter.Frame(master)

        # scrollbar
        scrollbar = tkinter.Scrollbar(frame)
        scrollbar.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, fill=tkinter.Y)

        # listbox
        listbox = tkinter.Listbox(frame, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        listbox.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, fill=tkinter.BOTH)

        # fill listbox
        for ID in self.data:
            listbox.insert(tkinter.END, self.formatItem(ID))

        return (frame, listbox, scrollbar)

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def destroyLB(self, e):
        for line in traceback.format_stack():
            print(line.strip())

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def formatItem(self, ID):
        """Creates a nice string representation of an item in the database."""

        return '{0}:{1}'.format(ID, self.data[ID])

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def listboxSelect(self, e):
        """Manages events when the selection changes in the database interface.

        e: (Event) tkinter event."""

        try:
            selection = self.listbox.get(self.listbox.curselection()[0])
        except:
            return

        # set description label
        ID = int(selection.split(':')[0])
        self.lblstr.set(self.data[ID])

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def view(self):
        """Displays database interface."""

        self.root = tkinter.Tk()

        # listbox frame
        self.frame, self.listbox, self.scrollbar = self.dataframe(self.root)
        self.frame.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.listboxSelect)
        self.listbox.bind('<Destroy>', self.destroyLB)

        # record display frame
        self.lblstr = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.lbl = tkinter.Label(self.root, textvariable=self.lblstr)
        self.lbl.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=tkinter.N)

        # buttons frame
        self.frame_btn = tkinter.Frame(self.root)
        self.frame_btn.grid(row=1, columnspan=2, sticky=tkinter.E+tkinter.W)

        # 'create new' button
        self.btn_new = tkinter.Button(
            self.frame_btn, text='+', command=self.addRecord)
        self.btn_new.grid(row=0, column=0)

        # 'delete record' button
        self.btn_del = tkinter.Button(
            self.frame_btn, text='-', command=self.delRecord)
        self.btn_del.grid(row=0, column=1)

        # display
        self.root.mainloop()
# Test =========================================================================

# OtherObject ==================================================================
class OtherObject:
    """An object with an ID and value."""

    def __init__ (self):
        self.ID = 0
        self.value = ''

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def create(self, master=None):
        """open a dialog for the user to entry a new object ID and value.

        master: (Tk or Toplevel) tkinter master widget."""

        self.stuff = tkinter.Toplevel(master)

        # ID
        tkinter.Label(self.stuff, text='ID: ').grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.IDvar = tkinter.StringVar(self.stuff)
        self.IDvar.set(self.ID)
        IDwidget = tkinter.Entry(self.stuff, textvariable=self.IDvar)
        IDwidget.grid(row=0, column=1)

        # value
        tkinter.Label(self.stuff, text='Value: ').grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.valueVar = tkinter.StringVar(self.stuff)
        self.valueVar.set(self.value)
        valueWidget = tkinter.Entry(self.stuff, textvariable=self.valueVar)
        valueWidget.grid(row=1, column=1)

        # OK button
        tkinter.Button(self.stuff, text='OK', command=self.OK).grid(row=2)

        self.stuff.mainloop()

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def OK(self):
        try: self.ID = int(self.IDvar.get())
        except: self.ID = 0
        self.value = self.valueVar.get()

        self.stuff.destroy()
# OtherObject ==================================================================
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bryan Oakley guided me to the exact problem that I was encountering:

(1) I created a second Tk object in my OtherObject class.

(2) I called mainloop in my OtherObject class.

Only one Tk object should exist and mainloop should only ever be called once, no matter how many windows are to be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating more than one instance of `Tk`. Tkinter is not designed to work like that and you will get unexpected behavior. You need to refactor your code so that you create an instance of `Tk` only once. If you need multiple windows, create instances of `Toplevel`.

*... time passes ... the code in the question gets updated ...*

In the updated version of your question you now are creating one instance of `Tk`, and then instances of `Toplevel`. This is good. However, you are also calling `mainloop` more than once which is a problem. Worse, you're redefining `self.root` which no doubt is part of the problem. You must call `mainloop` exactly once over the entirety of your program.

Comment: I just tried changing the OtherObject to Toplevel (in this dumbed-down code and in my master code) and it displays/works like it  did before, but I still have the same problem and error. I also tried to make the one in Test (the "main" window) also a Toplevel widget, and that gave me the same error but also opened an extra window that I didn't need at the beginning.

Comment: I just tried again, passing my master "root" widget (making it self.root) to the OtherObject and making the OtherObject's Toplevel widget use the Test's root as its master. Now it gives me an error at the same location (the listbox), but with the error:

_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".49660480.48661896"

Comment: @Breez: any code after the mainloop exists can't access anything related to Tkinter (widgets, StringVars, IntVars, etc) because at that point all of the Tkinter objects will have been destroyed.

Comment: Interesting - I thought that wouldn't be the case, since, as I said, the object's data was saved correctly to my database (i.e., to my file), but when I tried to to create a very basic Tk() with an Entry widget, and then tried to access the Entry widget, I got a similar error as before: "_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".51303760"". I'll fix my code accordingly and let you know what I come up with!

Comment: Nope, just tried it where I took care of assigning all elements (ID, data) in an OK method tied to a button and then destroyed the Toplevel widget. Of course, I removed other code following where I call the mainloop for OtherObject. Same error (.53064424.52074200).

Comment: @Breez: This is pretty simple: if you get an error that says `invalid command name ".50054760.50055432`, it means that the underlying widget has been destroyed. For you to get that message you must be trying to call a method on the widget after it has been destroyed.

Comment: Ah. Well, I don't understand why my listbox keeps getting destroyed. Geeze, that's confusing and weird, since my listbox select method still does what it's supposed to do when I select something from the listbox, which invokes a listbox method, and the same with deleting an item from the listbox. Anyway, the listbox seems to be being at least partially destroyed or disconnected from the rest of the thing.Any ideas on how I could work around this problem? I'm at a bit of a loss.

Comment: @Breez: the code in your question is still creating two instances of `tk.Tk()`. If you haven't fixed that, that's probably your problem. If you've fixed that, what you can try is to put a binding on `<Destroy>` for the listbox, then when that fires you can print a stack trace to see what's causing it to be destroyed.

Comment: I need help discerning what this stack traceback means, but it won't fit in this little comment area, so I'll post it as an "answer". I think that the listbox is probably destroyed when OtherObject is destroyed after its create method is invoked. Perhaps destroying a Toplevel object recursively destroys other objects in the master? Is there a more appropriate way to close Toplevel objects than calling destroy?

Comment: @Breez: killing a toplevel does *not* kill other objects in its master, it only kills its children. However, you're really borking things up by redefining self.root and calling `mainloop` more than once. There must be only one root window, and only one mainloop, for the life of the program.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your help directing me to a solution. I understood, after you told me, that calling Tk() more than once was wrong. I didn't understand, however, that calling mainloop more than once was incorrect. That problem is now corrected and I no longer get the error. The output still isn't what I like, but at least the error has been handled and something is being added to the listbox. Thank you again.